# angularjs - Multiple directives asking for new / isolated scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive to call a function only after iframe is loaded. However I get multidirective new / isolated scope error. My code snippet is as below.

```jsp
<iframe ng-src="{{src}}" ng-if="loginCheck" ng-show="false" data-iframe-on-load="iframeOnLoad" data-iframe-callback="testLoad()"></iframe>
```

js:

```js
directive('iframeOnLoad', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            callback: '&iframeCallBack'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.on('load', function() {
                return scope.callback();
            });
        }
    };
})
```

controller:

```js
$scope.loginCheck = true;
$scope.testLoad= function () {
    alert('loaded...');
};
```

Error:

> Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives [iframeOnLoad, iframeOnLoad] asking for new/isolated scope on

Comment: I only thing I could guess is your `iframeOnLoad` directive is defined twice.

Comment: No, I mean, for example, your JavaScript file that contains the directive declaration may be included twice in the script tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no issue with the code you posted except `&iframeCallBack` should be `&iframeCallback`. Otherwise consider changing `data-iframe-callback="testLoad()"` to `data-iframe-call-back="testLoad()"`.

The possible reason of the issue is that you have multiple directives that you create by copy-pasting an existing code of the directive and forgot to change the name of the directive to new one. Just search in your code for `iframeOnLoad`, I'm pretty sure you will find two directives with such name.

It is happening because AngularJS allows to register multiple directives with the same name. This pattern may be used to extend existing functionality of directive. However, you can create only one isolated scope for one DOM element, therefore two directives with the same name that require isolated scope are contradicting.

Working example see [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/8yvVEDfSabJn8HOSCLQ6?p=preview).

The same issue as yours reproduced [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/nclrqZKqqYLCjYBdUvZX).

Comment: I got the point you were stating and you are right. I renamed my directive and it worked. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is not the same name with two directives,the reason of the issue is that 
multiple directives have setting isolated scope at the same time in the one element.

Comment: Please try to post answer.

Comment: evenif the different name of directives ,one scope is isolated and another scope is ture or isolated also make the error,so the reason is that  the scope setting,not the same name of the directives, my english not well ,forgive me!

Comment: I have added that to your answer, I hope it will be helpful.